# multivariate numpy does not plot a normal distribution please help correct the mistake

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, distribution

Multivariate numpy package numpy.random.multivariate_normal..does not return a normal distribution plot...the example given at the site.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x,y = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean,cov,5000).T
plt.plot(x,y,'x'); plt.axis('equal'); plt.show()
```

When plotted does not give the normal distribution curve. I am new to numpy and I want to get a normal distribution curve..so please help.
I want to plot x, y and normal pdf in 2-dimension. That is, I want to show that x and y follow , "multivariate" normal distribution.

Answer (score 7):

`numpy.random.multivariate_normal()` *samples* from a multivariate normal distribution. Plotting the two coordinates from these samples against each other will not show you a 1D normal distribution curve. numpy itself does not have a function that will compute the 1D normal distribution curve itself. It's easy enough to compute yourself, though, if that's what you really want:

```
def normpdf(x, mean, std):
    z = (x - mean) / std
    return numpy.exp(-z**2/2.0)/numpy.sqrt(2*numpy.pi)/std
```

Comment: What I really want is..to plot values of x,y and normal distribution in 2-dimension space..and thanks for your help